# Teamviewer no connection on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, startup, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I want to be able to connect to the remote system via teamviewer even if it was restarted.

I can connect to the system if i run teamviewer manually, but can't do the same if system was restarted.

Daemon is running:

```
host@rtk:~$ teamviewer -info

 TeamViewer                      10.0.41499  (DEB) 

 teamviewerd status              ● teamviewerd.service - TeamViewer remote control daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/teamviewerd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Вт. 2015-07-28 17:33:27 MSK; 3min 21s ago
  Process: 1077 ExecStart=/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd -d (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1056 (teamviewerd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/teamviewerd.service
           ‣ 1056 /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd -d
```

However i can only connect system only after manual teamviewer execution:

```
> teamviewer
```

It's pretty simple to do what i want just specifying teamviewer in session startup applications. But session is protected by password, so teamviewer won't work until somebody get login to the system.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you restart the computer at startup Teamviewer loading faster then the daemon itself, so thats why the error message: "please start daemon" bla bla bla.

My solution was that add a `sleep 5` value in the `/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer` file. So to clarify my file looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# If you see this message, you probably attempted to start TeamViewer.
# Please open a terminal (Konsole, gnome-terminal, xterm),
# navigate to this folder (type 'cd /path/to/teamviewer' [Enter])
# then execute TeamViewer (type './teamviewer' [Enter])

sleep 5 #added line#
TV_SCRIPT_DIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -e "$0")")"
source "$TV_SCRIPT_DIR/tvw_main"

Main "$@"
```

---

Worked for me on Manjaro x64 0.8.13